# Bigcommerce api call using oauth token within ajax request

Tags: ajax, api, oauth, bigcommerce, request-headers

I want to use oauth api token details in ajax get request, but I am getting 401 unauthorized error.  I have checked my credentials within php file, but I can not run the ajax request using it.

I am stuck at how to pass headers within ajax request for Bigcommerce oauth login. 
API URL : https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{store-hash}/v3/catalog/categories

My working PHP code :

```
$headers = array(
"Accept: application/json",
"X-Auth-Client:".$client_id,
"X-Auth-Token:".$auth_token 
);
$chbig = curl_init($api_url); 
curl_setopt($chbig, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt($chbig, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
curl_setopt( $chbig, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
curl_setopt( $chbig, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
curl_setopt( $chbig, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
$result = curl_exec($chbig); //execute post
$http_status =  (string) curl_getinfo($chbig, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($chbig);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($http_status);
print_r($result);
```

Not working Js code :

```
$.ajax({
  url: api_url,
  headers: {
    "X-Auth-Client" : client_id,
    "X-Auth-Token" : auth_token ,
    'Accept':'application/json',
  },
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  type: "GET",
  success: function() { alert('Success!'); }
});
```

Please help me to find the solution...

Comment: Does the request generated by ajax look identical to the one generated by cURL (exact same headers, content etc?). You can use a tool like Fiddler to compare them.

Comment: No. I am not getting any request header which I have passed in ajax request

Comment: "Accept application/json" and "dataType: jsonp" contradict and conflict with each other. I think you should remove the jsonp bit. There's nothing in your cURL request which imitates this, and if you're expecting JSON back then you're not expecting a JSONP callback. Not the same thing.

Comment: yes but I used it to overcome error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource". And when I remove Accept : application/json, same error comes, no change.

Comment: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" is telling you you're not allowed to access that URL via ajax. If it's your server you can fix it by adding the appropriate CORS headers to the server's response. If it's not your server, then this is done by design and there's nothing you can do about it except go back to making the request via PHP. Telling jQuery to set the data type as JSONP might make that access-control error go away but it doesn't help you because it means the request no longer makes sense, because it's not a JSONP endpoint you're calling.

Comment: In other words, if the server isn't doing what you want, you can't fix it by asking it to pretend to be something it's not.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to request JSON not JSONP.

The hostname of the endpoint needs to be the same as the page that the script is running on to avoid the CORS issue.

In addition I would not recommend exposing API credentials on the front end.